# Getting OverflowException during calculation of a decimal Standard Deviation

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, standard-deviation

Calculating standard deviation by inserting values into a textbox. I have the following code:

```
public decimal calcStd(List<int> ppValuesArray)
{
    double std = 0;
    if (ppValuesArray.Count() > 0)
    {
        double avg = ppValuesArray.Average();

        double sum = ppValuesArray.Sum(d => Math.Pow(d - avg, 2));

        std = Math.Sqrt((sum) / ppValuesArray.Count() - 1);
    }
    decimal stdDev = Convert.ToDecimal(std);
    return (decimal)stdDev;

}
```

Problem is when I enter the same value multiple times the system crashed. e.g. 1,1,1,1 will crash it.

I'm getting the error:

> System.OverflowException: 'Value was either too large or too small for a Decimal.'

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're after the sample standard deviation, you've missed out on parenthesis in the -1 on the divisor, i.e.

```
std = Math.Sqrt((sum) / (ppValuesArray.Count() - 1));
```

The reason why you were getting the Overflow is because `decimal` can't represent the double value `NaN`, which is returned by `Math.Sqrt(double)` if you try and take the square root of a negative number.

Also, any reason why you take `List<int>` as input?  `decimal` or `double` seems less restrictive, depending on the type of data you are working with, e.g.

```
 public static decimal calcStd(IEnumerable<double> ppValuesArray)
```

Also, given that an attempt to get the sample StdDev of a single value will now yield a `DivideByZero` exception, would suggest that you change the guard to:

```
if (ppValuesArray.Count() > 1)
```

Comment: Thanks @StuartLC. That's perfect and fixes it. I knew it was something silly. I need the list to be of type int for this part of the project. Lots of other methods. Cheers for the fix. Much appreciated.